# NSCollectionView in 10.6/Xcode 3.2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nscollectionview, copywithzone

in Xcode 3.1.2 I used to load the nib of the `NSCollectionViewItem` in my subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` like this:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{   
    id result = [super copyWithZone:zone];

    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"PersonView" owner:result];

    return result;
}
```

In Xcode 3.2 under 10.6 the same method doesn't yield to an error, but it doesn't load the view in the `NSCollectionView` either.

Is there something else that needs to be done to make the view show up? 
Or is there even a better way of doing this that comes with the change of `NSCollectionItem`'s superclass to `NSViewController`?

After all, overriding `copyWithZone` to achieve this standard functionality always seemed like a hack to me. I think one should be able to specify the nib that's supposed to be used in IB, but it seems like Apple doesn't think so.

I did have a look at the example that is available in the documentation, but there the `NSCollectionViewItem` is instantiated programmatically using `initWithNibName`, but I would like to create it in the IB.

**UPDATE**:

I did what kperryua suggested, but now I can't access outlets from the `NSCollectionViewItem`. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)object {

    if (object) {
        [labelName setValue:[object name]];
    }
}
```

I binded the label name to the file owner which is my `NSCollectionViewItem`. That used to work perfectly in 10.5, but now the outlet is not assigned(I checked that with GDB).

[image showing the bindings http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/671/picya.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/671/picya.png)

**UPDATE 2**:

I also binded the `NSCollectionView`'s `itemPrototype` to my subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem`(PersonController).

[image showing bindings http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/4672/pic2d.png](http://img503.imageshack.us/img503/4672/pic2d.png)

Now both the `File's Owner` of the `PersonView.nib` and the `itemPrototype` of the `NSCollectionView` point to my subclass.

[image showing console output http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6184/pic3.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/6184/pic3.png)

As you can see in the screenshot the item are displayed, but the text of the label can't be changed as the outlet `labelName` isn't accessible.

I also logged the name that I'm trying to set to make sure it isn't 'Name'.

What needs to be done to change the label's value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Snow Leopard makes this much easier. In IB, click on the NSCollectionViewItem and set the nib name and bundle name (just leave it blank for the main bundle). In your PersonView nib, make the NSCollectionViewItem the File's Owner and connect the -view outlet to a view in that nib. (It looks like you might have this set up like that already in that nib.) Everything else should be automatic, and overriding copyWithZone: shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It's showing up now, but I can't access the outlets I binded to the FileOwner of the nib that contains the Item's View. Do I have to do that differently now too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Did you make sure that both your File's Owner AND the prototype item are both declared as instances of your subclass? If the prototype item is still NSCollectionViewItem, then the copied items will be of that same class, not your custom class. (I ran into the same problem while trying to reproduce what you described.)

Comment: Yes, I have changed both of them. See my second update for details.

Comment: I really can't say what you should do next. I've replicated your scenario and made sure to do everything I suggested to do, and it works for me. Give everything a second pass and make sure you've done everything. Perhaps try breaking on -[NSCollectionViewItem copyWithZone:] in the debugger, root out the pointer to 'self' ($esi I think on x86_64, $ebp+8 on i386, and check the class. If it's still NSCollectionViewItem, you know you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

To sync the property of the `representedObject` with the Value of an IB Element, you might want to use the Cocoa-bindings. Bind the Value of the TextField to the **Model Key Path** `representedObject.name` of the **File's Owner** in this case.

I had that working with 10.6 Xcode 3.2 <del>but what can't get to work is what you did: Connecting an IB Element to an Outlet of my CollectionViewItem. I have a custom subclass of CollectionViewItem and everything set up as you have. But when running the application it fails stating</del>

<del>[NSTextField copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210a60
    2009-10-19 13:05:18.772 WrapperTest[24122:a0f] An uncaught exception was raised
    2009-10-19 13:05:18.774 WrapperTest[24122:a0f] -[NSTextField copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210a60
    2009-10-19 13:05:18.779 WrapperTest[24122:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTextField copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210a60'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x977f658a __raiseError + 410
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9767ff49 objc_exception_throw + 56
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x978429db -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
     3   CoreFoundation                      0x9779e026 ___forwarding___ + 950
     4   CoreFoundation                      0x9779dbf2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
     5   CoreFoundation                      0x97789a5a -[NSObject(NSObject) copy] + 42
     6   AppKit                              0x918ce1d7 -[NSViewController setTitle:] + 70
     7   AppKit                              0x91167dab -[NSNibOutletConnector establishConnection] + 406 ...</del>

<del>I'm not sure why those `NSTextFields` are missing their `copyWithZone` since they should implement it</del>

I fixed that, I wasn't aware, that I needed to declare those Outlets as properties of the view, everything including bindings seem to work.